# class initialization with getting json by ajax always fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie of JavaScript. I want to make a class which communicate to Flickr Web API with Ajax when initialized.

**Photo2.js**

```
  var Photo2;

  Photo2 = (function() {

    Photo2.prototype.json = null;

    function Photo2() {
      $.getJSON('http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?', {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.photos.search',
        api_key: '7965a8bc5a2a88908e8321f3f56c80ea',
        user_id: '29242822@N00',
        per_page: '100'
      }, function(data) {
        this.json = data.photos.photo;
      });
    }

    return Photo2;

  })();
```

But when initialized as `photo2 = new Photo2` this does not have `photo2.json`.

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: I don't use the above, but with json callbacks, that usually means the request is json with padding, which is `format : 'jsonp'` I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried both `json` and `jsonp` but failed.

Comment: Newer versions of jQuery seem to have some trouble getting JSONP using $.getJSON. Have you tried using $.ajax instead?

Comment: I think the problem you will have is that `Photo2` is only defined inside that context, if you want to do `var photo2 = new Photo2()` outside there, it should fail. Maybe you want to rewrite the code...

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Sorry I forgot removing brackets. The above code is newest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really rewrite your code. It's complicated and hard to figure out what you'd like to achieve.

First of all, getting data from server is asynchronous so you cannot be sure that after creating an instance of Photo2 `json` property will be defined.

Next things is that it's really bad idea to make server call while initializing an object. I advice you following solution:

```
(function() {
  var Photo2 = function(callback) {
    this.json = null;
  };

  Photo2.prototype.getData =  function(successCallback) {
    var self = this;

    $.getJSON('http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?', {
        format: 'json',
        method: 'flickr.photos.search',
        api_key: '7965a8bc5a2a88908e8321f3f56c80ea',
        user_id: '29242822@N00',
        per_page: '100'
      }, function(data) {
        self.json = data.photos.photo;
        typeof successCallback == 'function' && successCallback();
      }); 
  };

  var photo = new Photo2();
  photo.getData(function successCallback() {
    console.log('Data loaded', photo.json);
  });
}).call(this);
```

Working demo here: http://jsbin.com/ureyas/1/edit

Comment: I am trying to understand above code... by the way, your JSBin tool is fascinating !

Comment: @weed: it's not mine :) But I really recommend you to use it while you share the JS code. If you have additional questions, feel free to ask here.